# profile linking times with gcc/g++ and ld

Tags: gcc, profiling, g++, linker, ld

I'm using g++ to compile and link a project consisting of about 15 c++ source files and 4 shared object files.  Recently the linking time more than doubled, but I don't have the history of the makefile available to me.  Is there any way to profile g++ to see what part of the linking is taking a long time?

**Edit:** After I noticed that the makefile was using -O3 optimizations all the time, I managed to halve the linking time just by removing that switch.  Is there any good way I could have found this without trial and error?

**Edit:** I'm not actually interested in profiling how ld works.  I'm interested in knowing how I can match increases in linking time to specific command line switches or object files.

Answer (score 2):

Profiling `g++` will prove futile, because `g++` doesn't perform linking, the linker `ld` does.

Profiling `ld` will also likely not show you anything interesting, because linking time is most often dominated by disk I/O, and if your link isn't, you wouldn't know what to make of the profiling data, unless you understand `ld` internals.

If your link time is noticeable with only 15 files in the link, there is likely something wrong with your development system [1]; either it has a disk that is on its last legs and is constantly retrying, or you do not have enough memory to perform the link (linking is often RAM-intensive), and your system swaps like crazy.

Assuming you are on an ELF based system, you may also wish to try the new `gold` linker (part of binutils), which is often several times faster than the GNU `ld`.

[1] My typical links involve 1000s of objects, produce 200+MB executables, and finish in less than 60s.

Answer (score 2):

If you have just hit your RAM limit, you'll be probably able to hear the disk working, and a system activity monitor will tell you that. But if linking is still CPU-bound (i.e. if CPU usage is still high), that's not the issue. And if linking is IO-bound, the most common culprit can be runtime info. Have a look at the executable size anyway.

To answer your problem in a different way: are you doing heavy template usage? For each usage of a template with a different type parameter, a new instance of the whole template is generated, so you get more work for the linker. To make that actually noticeable, though, you'd need to use some library really heavy on templates. A lot of ones from the Boost project qualifies - I got template-based code bloat when using Boost::Spirit with a complex grammar. And ~4000 lines of code compiled to 7,7M of executable - changing one line doubled the number of specializations required and the size of the final executable. Inlining helped a lot, though, leading to 1,9M of output.

Shared libraries might be causing other problems, you might want to look at documentation for -fvisibility=hidden, and it will improve your code anyway. From GCC manual for -fvisibility:

> ```
>  Using this feature can very substantially
>  improve linking and load times of shared object libraries, produce
>  more optimized code, provide near-perfect API export and prevent
>  symbol clashes.  It is *strongly* recommended that you use this in
>  any shared objects you distribute.
> ```

In fact, the linker normally must support the possibility for the application or for other libraries to override symbols defined into the library, while typically this is not the intended usage. Note that using that is not for free however, it does require (trivial) code changes.

The link suggested by the docs is: http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility

Answer (score 1):

Both gcc and g++ support the `-v` verbose flag, which makes them output details of the current task.

If you're interested in really profiling the tools, you may want to check out [Sysprof](http://www.daimi.au.dk/~sandmann/sysprof/) or [OProfile](http://oprofile.sourceforge.net/news/).