# how to find the bottleneck in linking?

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, ld

I have a project which is very slow in linking (~ 2mins and I feel this is slow). **I am aware of faster linker such as gold or lld, but I cannot change a linker.**

I used a lot of C++11 templates in my code and I suspect that some template code may get instantiated repeatedly in multiple object files, but I have no clue  how to find if this is true.

**I wonder if there is a way to profile the whole linking stage like what we do to profile a program and try to find the bottleneck.** For example, a tool that I can use to inspect how many times a symbol (unnecessarily) appear in different object files and then get discarded during linking can help me to find out which template code might be the cause.  The above about repeated symbols in object files is only my speculation - **I need an evidence based approach.** Then based on this finding, I will think about how to improve my code to reduce linking time.

I use CMake, GNU g++ and ld as my build tools and I'm working in Linux platform.

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, but questions for tools are off-topic. You might find https://github.com/adrianstone55/SymbolSort to be useful though.

Comment: @MaxLanghof Asking for tool recommendations is off-topic, asking for specific help with a single specific tool is okay.

Comment: Using "explicit template instantiation" can sometimes help. You may also find the following of interest: https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2014/03/10/making-compiles-slow/

Comment: @JesperJuhl thanks for the link but I got too many template classes/functions to explicitly instantiate and I'm not even sure if this is the cause of the slow linking at all! That's why I want an evidence based approach - is it really caused by template? if it is, which class/function is the culprit?

Comment: Why not to profile ld itself using say perf + flame graphs?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/403914/72178

Comment: Techniques to reduce link time will be specific to your compiler and linker and will often trade off by causing larger incremental compilation times to reduce link times.   Some techniques, such as explicit template instantiation, can also affect development/maintenance effort.   Two minute link time suggests a pretty small project though - just use it as an excuse to stretch your legs and or go outside to refocus eyes away from the screen.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude True, I should have been more precise there.

Comment: How about just using `--trace` and staring at the output — how fast (and in what order, esp. if you have static libraries) the input files are processed — for starters?

Comment: Thanks @MaxLanghof I'll try your recommended tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to approach this problem is to dump defined symbols of each object file and archive included in the link with `nm --demangle --defined-only --extern-only` and build a mapping `{symbol, definition_count}`. Sort this mapping by `definition_count` high-to-low and print.